# Spring Boot, JPA, AWS-RDS(PostgreSql), Multiple schema

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

Below is my project technical stack

```
-> Spring Boot
-> AWS RDS(PostgreSql)
-> AWS Secret Manager
-> JPA
```

I am accessing RDS instance using Secret Manager in my application.

Below is application.yml configuration

```
spring:
datasource:
url: jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql://<domain>:5432/testdb
username: secret/test
driver-class-name:com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerPostgreSQLDriver
```

My problem is for same DB instance I have muliplte schema (dev_trx and dev_pub).
Product table is in dev_trx schema and Order table is in dev_pub schema.
So I have my Entity class as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dev_trx")
public class Product
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dev_pub")
public class Order
```

My project also need to have for multiple environments Dev, QA, Prod. Can anyone please
help me how can I have schema name dynamic as per environment.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should go for different db for different env, that will be easy to manage.
However for this you problem you can use Interceptor , you can use this link https://naveen.me/jpa-dynamic-table-name-entity/ to explore